# Defining character length for custom attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I have added custom attribute with type of VARCHAR and it is also added in attribute table.

But I want the length of field as 1000 char. I also checked the eav_attribute table but it does not have any field for character length.

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, ‘magento_username’, [

‘type’ => ‘varchar’,

‘label’ => ‘Custom Username’,

‘input’ => ‘text’,

‘required’ => false,

‘visible’ => true,

‘user_defined’ => true,

‘sort_order’ => 1000,

‘position’ => 1000,

‘system’ => 0,

]);
```

Do I need to add type as "Text" so attribute will save in text table?

Or here can I add in code anything to increase the character length?

Comment: ‘type’ => ‘varchar’ -> means save data to *_varchar table.

Comment: Yes got your point but how do we specify the character length ?